# fatal: Commit found, use 'git ftp push' to sync

Tags: github, ftp, yaml, circleci

I am getting this error in my circleci yaml file when uploading to my ftp site via my github, there is definitely a change for it to commit but i'm getting this error:

```
HEAD is now at 76a63d8 Updated config.yml
fatal: Commit found, use 'git ftp push' to sync. Exiting.
```

..

Even though I have that in my yaml file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8-browsers

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: 
          name: Deploy Master Branch
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            echo "Deploying project ..."
            git ftp init --user ${username} --passwd ${password} ${ftp_location}
            - git reset --hard
            - git ftp push


workflows:
  version: 2
  master-deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

yes i am also getting the same error and i fixed it with this code

```
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get -qq install git-ftp
        git config git-ftp.user ${username}
        git config git-ftp.url ${ftp_location}
        git config git-ftp.password ${password}
        git ftp push
```

Please follow this code